# pandas shuffle last N rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can I shuffle the last N rows in a pandas dataframe? When I say "shuffle", I mean to randomly change the order of rows. This is what I've tried so far. I can't figure out how to properly reset the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'d1': np.linspace(0, 1, 10)})
pd.concat([dat[:5], dat[5:].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)])
```

output:

```
         d1
0  0.000000
1  0.111111
2  0.222222
3  0.333333
4  0.444444
0  0.777778
1  0.666667
2  0.888889
3  1.000000
4  0.555556
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

dat = pd.DataFrame({'d1': np.linspace(0, 1, 10)})
np.random.shuffle(dat.values[5:])
print(dat)
```

**Output**

```
d1
0  0.000000
1  0.111111
2  0.222222
3  0.333333
4  0.444444
5  0.666667
6  1.000000
7  0.777778
8  0.555556
9  0.888889
```

Or, if you prefer, [permutation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = pd.DataFrame({'d1': np.linspace(0, 1, 10)})
dat.values[5:] = np.random.permutation(dat.values[5:])

print(dat)
```

**Output**

```
         d1
0  0.000000
1  0.111111
2  0.222222
3  0.333333
4  0.444444
5  0.555556
6  0.888889
7  0.777778
8  1.000000
9  0.666667
```

Comment: What is going on here? The code works perfectly but I'm baffled by it. Why doesn't `dat.values[5:]` need to be be set equal to something new? Does np.random.shuffle always do things in place like this?

Comment: @kilojoules yes shuffle does it in place

Answer (score 2):

For default index add parameter `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'d1': np.linspace(0, 1, 10)})
df = pd.concat([dat[:5], dat[5:].sample(frac=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Another solution is use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) only for last rows and assign back `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for prevent alignment of indices:

```
dat.iloc[5:] = dat.iloc[5:].sample(frac=1).values
```

Numpy solution with [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) working inplace:

```
np.random.shuffle(dat.iloc[5:].values)
```

---

```
print (df)
         d1
0  0.000000
1  0.111111
2  0.222222
3  0.333333
4  0.444444
5  0.666667
6  0.888889
7  1.000000
8  0.555556
9  0.777778
```